# How to fill in missing values in Pandas dataframe according to pattern in column?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Suppose I have a dataframe with a column as follows:

```
Column
10
NaN
20
NaN
30
```

I want each row to be filled in with increments of 5 so that the final output would appear like:

```
Column
10
15
20
25
30
```

I've tried using `np.arange` and `.reindex()` but haven't had much luck. I'm looking for an iterative approach instead of simply manually filling in. Can anyone please help with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with `interpolate`

```
df['Column']=df.Column.interpolate()
Out[86]: 
0    10.0
1    15.0
2    20.0
3    25.0
4    30.0
Name: Column, dtype: float64
```